How to Model Repo Financing in Bond Future Basis with Central Bank Meetings and Year-End/Quarter-End Considerations
I am looking for guidance ( or reference material) on how to model the repo financing component when trading bond futures basis. Specifically, I am assuming the use of an overnight repo rate that is rolled daily. I would like to understand how to model this for different scenarios:
When there is a central bank meeting between today and the futures delivery date, where potential rate changes could affect the repo rates.
During a year-end or quarter-end period, when repo rates tend to behave differently due to balance sheet constraints and funding pressures.
How would I adjust my model to account for these events, and what factors should I consider in each case?

Not sure what there is to model here. The repo component to delivery determines part of the carry of the position. If you assume a particular path for the repo rate you should be able to figure out what your carry is to delivery and thus what the net basis of the position is as of today (ignoring specialness etc).

So for eg. If you  think the fed will cut part way to delivery you could just use a blended repo rate to term. Assuming no liquidity event, sofr should trade at or below on rrp. From there its fairly easy to work out your bnoc
